# "x is not a constructor" even though it's defined

Tags: javascript, class, constructor

**client.js**

```
const CSGO = require('./csgo')

module.exports = class Client {
    constructor() {

    }

    csgo(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(new CSGO(data))
            .catch(err => reject(err))
        })
    }

};
```

**csgo.js**

```
module.export = class CSGO {
    constructor(content) {
        // super();
        this.content = content;
    }

    parseData() {
        console.log(content + ' it works')
    }
}
```

**test.js**

```
var client = require('./src/client.js')

const game = new client();

game.csgo('hello')
```

I'm trying to pass contents from test.js => client.js => csgo.js, but when I try to call `game.csgo(contents')` then from the client create a `new CSGO` with the data, I am getting a `TypeError` saying that CSGO is not a constructor. What should I do?

Comment: `Client` or `client`? Remember that JavaScript is *case sensitive*. If it's a typo from rewriting the code into the question, then please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that you can copy-paste as-is instead. Rewriting code like that may introduce unrelated errors that confuse. Or maybe even sometimes *fix* the problem by mistake, making the question moot.

Comment: It's `module.exports` not `module.export`.

Comment: Your `csgo` method doesn't work anyway. `resolve` returns nothing, calling `.catch` on it is a mistake. Also if you just want to immediately resolve a new promise with a value, use `Promise.resolve`. Or why are you using a promise at all here?

Comment: +1 to @bergi's comment above too. There are a few odd things in this code beyond the typo. But the error is purely because nothing is being exported from that file. So it's not a constructor, but it's also not _anything_. It's a shame that the error doesn't pick that up.

Comment: @Bergi @Matt Fletcher alright, so I fixed the `exports` typo and removed the promise. Upon running it, I get nothing. How do I run the `parseData` without calling it?

Comment: @Jack "*How do I run the `parseData` without calling it?*" makes no sense. Of course you have to call it. Something like `game = new client; game.csgo('hello').parseData()`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just a typo. You have `module.export` when you mean `module.exports` in csgo.js